# How can I use xpath 2.0 in query to dom4j object in java

Tags: java, xpath-2.0, dom4j

I need set query to the dom4j document like 
`Node fromTag = document.selectSingleNode("//*:from");` 
without prefix in select query. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM4J supports XPath 1.0 only, but you can use this expression instead:

```
document.selectSingleNode("//*[local-name()='from']");
```